# How do I extending a formula without dragging across the entire range to extend over?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

How can I extend a formula from, for example, cell A1 to A500 without dragging it the whole way? Is there any formula or menu to complete this task without dragging it the entire way?

Answer (score 1):

If you `double-click` the drag handle, it will automatically fill down to all relevant cells.

EG - in cell A1 I have the formula `=SUM(B1+C1)`. If I have numbers in B1 down to B500 and double click the drag handle for A1, it will automatically fill down.

Answer (score 0):

And if you don't have a conveniently filled set of cells, there are a couple of ways to make it easier:

- Shift-click extends a selection, so click to select A1, scroll until A500 is visible, then shift-click A500. You still have to *scroll* to A500, but at least you don't have to *drag* there.
- Use `Go To...` in the `Edit` menu. You can enter a reference to select a group of cells, so choose `Edit` > `Go To...`, enter `A1:A500`, hit return/enter or click `OK`.

Once you have the cells selected, then you can do a fill in whatever direction makes sense (so `Fill Down` in the `A1:A500` example).